# How to output to console in PHPStorm when debugging Javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, phpstorm, javascript-debugger

Javascript debugging is great in PHPStorm, but how do I simply output a string to the console from JS?

In Firebug, I would add something like:

`console.log('Internet successfully downloaded');`

What is the PHPStorm-debugger equivalent?

Comment: What browser do you use? It's supported for Firefox (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55311) but not for Chrome (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76789).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's now [supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-4378) for both Chrome and Firefox.

---

Original answer from 2012:

<s>This feature is supported only for **Firefox** at the moment. If you are using **Chrome**, please [vote for the related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76789).</s>